# How can change link's color in CSS

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink, tags

i have many link in my content

how can found and change color all link in div tag when show content to user ?

like that :

```
pleas visit my own site's : telegram.org , www.google.com , www.wikipedia.com , ... 
and send mail to : mymail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the color of links in all pages or app then do this in css..

```
a {
    color: red;/*color name, color code or rbg*/
}
```

if you want to change the specific link color ....

```
a.highlight {
   color: red;
}
```

if you want to change the all links color in specific div .....

```
.content a{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style a link you should use css to do this:

```css
.new_link {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="new_link" href="#link2" id="link1">Go to next link</a>
  <br>
  <a class="new_link" href="#link1" id="link2">Go to link1</a>
  Some other text that will not be styled
</div>
```

Here i added a class in the link elements (`<a>` element).

By adding a class they get the css styling.
The styling i choose here where:
Background-color
color (text-color)

You can make create css rules (like above) for all `<a>` elements on your page.
An other possibility is to add a class to the `<div>` element and select all links inside this div. All of this is possible with css.